# Why do asyncore tests fail in compiled Python 3.6?

Tags: python, python-3.x, macos-sierra, asyncore

I have compiled Python 3.6 and ran tests but 2 of them failed:

```
======================================================================
FAIL: test_handle_expt (test.test_asyncore.TestAPI_UseIPv4Poll)
----------------------------------------------------------------------
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/andrei/Python/cpython/Lib/test/test_asyncore.py", line 676, in test_handle_expt
    self.loop_waiting_for_flag(client)
  File "/Users/andrei/Python/cpython/Lib/test/test_asyncore.py", line 516, in loop_waiting_for_flag
    self.fail("flag not set")
AssertionError: flag not set

======================================================================
FAIL: test_handle_expt (test.test_asyncore.TestAPI_UseIPv6Poll)
----------------------------------------------------------------------
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/andrei/Python/cpython/Lib/test/test_asyncore.py", line 676, in test_handle_expt
    self.loop_waiting_for_flag(client)
  File "/Users/andrei/Python/cpython/Lib/test/test_asyncore.py", line 516, in loop_waiting_for_flag
    self.fail("flag not set")
AssertionError: flag not set

----------------------------------------------------------------------
Ran 101 tests in 21.140s

FAILED (failures=2, skipped=6)
test test_asyncore failed
```

What can go wrong there?

Comment: you're using a Mac, right?

Comment: Yeah, just saw the ticket http://bugs.python.org/issue28087

Comment: Was writing an answer either way :-). By the way, you have a much better chance of resolving your issue by creating an issue on bugs.python.org after scanning for relevant issues.

Comment: Saturday is kinda dead there, I got no response. Here -- in 4 min :-D

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This has been brought up twice on the bug tracker:

- [Issue 28456 -- Test failures under macOS 10.12 Sierra](https://bugs.python.org/issue28456)
- [Issue 28087 -- macOS 12 poll syscall returns prematurely](https://bugs.python.org/issue28087)

The first was closed as a dupe of the second and the second one has not yet been fixed. In short, [the `poll()` system function](https://developer.apple.com/legacy/library/documentation/Darwin/Reference/ManPages/man2/poll.2.html) is apparently [broken in Sierra](https://daniel.haxx.se/blog/2016/10/11/poll-on-mac-10-12-is-broken/). You'll need to wait for them to get done fixing it. Until then, it is safe to ignore these failures.